# Verify linq query

Tags: c#, .net, xml, vb.net, linq

I'm converting vb code to c#, and unfortunately I don't have now the access to database, and I can't check if my code is good.

```
 Dim xmlDoc As XDocument
                xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result)
                Dim supportNode = xmlDoc...<SUPPORT>
                PhoneNumberLabel.Text = supportNode.First().Element("SUPPORTPHONE").Value
                EmailLabel.Text = supportNode.First().Element("SUPPORTEMAIL").Value
                TrainingPhoneLabel.Text = supportNode.First().Element("TRAININGPHONE").Value
```

and here is this code in c#...I think

```
XDocument xmlDoc = default(XDocument);
                    xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);
                    var supportNode = xmlDoc.Descendants("SUPPORT");

                    PhoneNumberLabel.Text = supportNode.First().Element("SUPPORTPHONE").Value;
                    EmailLabel.Text = supportNode.First().Element("SUPPORTEMAIL").Value;
                    TrainingPhoneLabel.Text = supportNode.First().Element("TRAININGPHONE").Value;
```

Could you check that it's ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both source codes are equivalent.